# Compare HTML5 date input with Angular2 date

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I wanted compare the date (input type="date" in HTML5) with the date Objekt in Angular2 but there is no way to compare them. I there a easy way to do it ?

```
<label> Create Date: </label>
<input class="form-control" [ngModel]="chart.createDate" 
        (ngModelChange)="chart.createDate = $event" 
        type="date" 
        data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY"
        required #createDate="ngModel" name="createDate"/>

<div *ngIf="Date.parse(chart.createDate).getTime() < dateControll.getTime()">
      - date is older than today
</div>
```

Comment: Expose service method to the view that compares 2 dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
if (varDate1.valueOf() > varDate2.valueOf()) {
  // do this and that...
}
```

but both needs to be defined as Date in Angular...